# Почему форма имеет высоту родительского элемента и кушает фон?

Tags: html, jquery, css, css3, позиционирование

Всем привет. Есть блок с фоном, описанием и в нем форма. [демонстрация](http://jsfiddle.net/9bz8re5y/)
Почему форма имеет такую же высоту, как и родительский `<div class="product-frame">`? Хочу не меняя структуры html поместить форму справа от описания, но если просто добавить ширину `.content-description { width:50%; }` а форме
`form { float:left;}`, то скушается фон блока, притом что удаление `overflow: hidden;` ничего не дает. Что можно предпринять?

```css
.product-frame {
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.content-description {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-frame">
  <div class="content-description">
    <p>Описание описание описание описание описание описание описание описание описание</p>
    <p>Описание описание описание описание описание описание описание описание описание</p>
    <p>Описание описание описание описание описание описание описание описание описание</p>
  </div>
  <form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="3350">
    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="3350">
    <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" value="3357">
    <button type="submit" class="add_to_cart_button">Купить</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Помогло добавление `overflow:hidden;` содержащему див и

```
.content-description {
float:left;
width:50%;
overflow:visible;
}
form {
float:left;
width:50%;
}
```

Итог - [здесь](http://jsfiddle.net/9bz8re5y/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо и блоку .content-description и форме добавить

```
float: left;
width: 50%;
```

А контейнеру .product-frame добавьте overflow: hidden; или clearfix, если вы его используете.

Comment: помогло. а вс же - почему так происходит? хочу понять сам механизм

Comment: Всё просто - float изначально предназначен для обтекания картинок текста. Чтоб использовать это свойство для колонок, все колонки должны иметь свойство float:left или float:right. Кроме того, после колонок нужно "очистить поток" - присвоить контейнеру overflow:hidden или после колонок поставить блок со свойством clear:both или же использовать clearfix (погуглите "очистка потока в html" и "clearfix")

Comment: да, ок @Сергей я понимаю, что такое чистка потока, но непонятно почему форма без `float` занимает все пространство? если бы у `content-description` было абсолютное позиционирование - это одно или `float` в данном случае тоже выбивается из потока - да?

Comment: Потому что <form> - блочный элемент и по умолчанию занимает всю доступную ширину. А float у блока с описаниями выбивается из потока, да, и получается что форма как блочный элемент не обтекает этот блок, а содержание формы - обтекает.